# Is it normal for backlashes to appear in .csv file cells?

Tags: r

I am reading a csv file and encountering backslashes in cells. Is this normal? If not, how can the file be read without backslashes in cells?

The file was created simply by inputting text in cells (e.g., "yes", "no" in cell 1). Ultimately, I would like to use these cells to label factors and need the cells to print in normal format (e.g., "yes" "no")

```
> dput(test_codes)
structure(list(col1 = "\"yes\", \"no\"", col2 = "\"true once\", \"true twice\""), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

> test_codes[1,1]
[1] "\"yes\", \"no\""
```

@jpsmith being added for responding to a related question.

[image]

Comment: Use `cat(test_codes[1,1])` to see the "real" value. The default `print()` method escapes special characters such as quotes.

Comment: @MrFlick cat() seems to print without special characters. Say I am trying to recode (e.g., `data$var <- dplyr::recode(data$var, cat(labels$var), .default = "nothing"`), what should I wrap labels$var with to make the recode work?

Comment: `cat()` doesn't change the value in any way; it just changes how it's printed to the console. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `recode()`. It don't see how this related to the example you provided in the original question.

Comment: Consider only assigning one value to each column - when you are reading in the file, it is breaking it up at every comma which is splitting your columns arbitrarily. The `\"` just means `"` as the `\\` is the escape character. So you can see that's what its doing.